# ASP.NET MVC, Layers, Models, Repositories etc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have some questions after reading an article called `Layered Application Guidelines` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658109.aspx).

For example, I have an ASP.NET MVC application. In my application I have some Entities (Models), Repositories, UnitOfWork and DbContext. And some Views and Controllers as well.

How to split them into layers according to an article above?

As far as I understand, Views and (maybe) Controllers reside in a Presentation Layer. Entities (Models) in Business Layer and Repositories, UnitOfWork and DbContext in Data Layer.

Am I right or mistaken? I'm very-very unsure about it.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "split them into layers?"

Comment: Models and Entities have different points of view. Entities (Domain Classes) are how your Data Layer & Business Layer use data. 
Models are how your Presentation(View) uses data. Use a tool like AutoMapper to transpose in the controller.

Comment: Domain Entities should reside in BL or DL? Thanks!

Comment: Entities are data access.  Models are supposed to contain your business logic.  Depending on what ORM you're using, it might be possible to use your model to generate your entities.  You should map from your models to View Models which are consumed by the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Views and Controllers should reside in the presentation layer. Your models should also reside in the presentation layer. Models reflect a view model that is used for presentation only. Entities should represent data and should not be sent to the View. In the presentation later, the models should be populated from the entities. You are correct in that your DbContext and UnitOfWork should be in the data layer.

Comment: In the MVC projects I have worked on entities are used in all three layers.

Comment: @DennisKiesel I have seen lots of that too. ViewModels and `AutoMapper` are your friends in that situation though!

Comment: No the same entities are used in all layers. The main thing to avoid is using an entity in a view. Create a model from the entity and pass it along to your view.

Answer (score 3):

The way the layers are separated will depend on the scope of your application. For a small one, Areas may suffice. For a larger project, or a project which may become large, you should look into creating separate solutions for each layer. This is known as an n-tier approach, and can be seen when looking at the excellent example at http://prodinner.codeplex.com/.

Answer (score 2):

Entity Framework entities (along with the framework) are your data layer. In many applications they also become part of your business layer - and it is debatable whether or not this is good (I personally don't like that, but when you abstract it with say the repository model there is a good argument that you are losing some of the benefits provided by EF).

Depending on how you separate out your code (and it sounds like you are using the repository pattern) you may have a repositories containing some business logic, or have a services layer as well (my preference for 3 tier applications) where business logic (mostly) happens.

I would argue that you should be considering View Models as well as part of your presentation model - but if you are using MVC and data-annotations (which are excellent for this job) to validate your model you have just piled a bunch of business logic in to them.

The most important place to prevent business logic from creeping into is your presentation layer, and most importantly your Views and Controllers. The approach to how you structure the rest of your application depends heavily on the framework you choose, the scale of your application and the deployment structure of the application.

So to be as clear as possible this is what *I do**:

**Views**          <--Presentation layer only

**Controllers**    <--Presentation layer only (might end up with slightly 'fat' controller in some instances, e.g. .NET Membership login)

**View Models**    <--Presentation layer, but if doing validations here often business rules are also being tested.

**Service Layer**  <--Business Layer if used

**Repositories**   <--Could be Data layer only, or mix of business layer. If you do the repository pattern try and avoid exposing your DbSets directly, as this immediately defeats the abstraction you are attempting to provide (potential exceptions to this, e.g. - .Net Membership)

**Entities**       <--Data layer, possibly with also business logic depending on how you structure your application.

**Not to be taken as authoritative*

Answer (score 2):

- View models/Views/Controllers - presentation layer
- Entities - business layer

[The repository mediates between the data source layer and the business layers of the application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx)

The DbContext [Represents a combination of the Unit-Of-Work and Repository patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext%28v=vs.103%29.aspx), so if you are implementing a repository and unit of work on top of it could mean that you should consider to [limit your abstractions](http://ayende.com/blog/154209/limit-your-abstractions-refactoring-toward-reduced-abstractions). (This last point may not apply in your case, I couldn't say without knowing more about your design).

Comment: Limit abstractions? What do you mean? Thanks.

Comment: If you are implementing either a repository or an unit of work in an object that uses your DbContext it may be that you are introducing more abstractions than strictly necessary. It could be that the repository on top of the DbContext repository isn't doing anything usefull except introducing yet another layer which is abstracting away what is really going on. I am not saying that there's one correct answer, you just need to consider what is right for your application. Never introduce layers and abstractions that aren't really needed. Ayende writes about this in the post I linked